# How to resolve this error: await and cursor does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, .net

```
private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var db = mongo.GetDatabase("milk123");
    mongo.Connect();
    var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("stock123");
    using (var cursor = await col.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToCursorAsync())
    {
        while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
        {
            foreach (var doc in cursor.Current)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(doc);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On executing it i am getting the following error:

await and cursor does not exist in current context.

Comment: What error? This is not an automatic debugger service.

Comment: You should read about [how to ask good question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

`await` keyword can be used inside `async` methods only

[about async](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx)